# console.log() not working inside Angular controller

Tags: angular, controller, console.log

There have been several posts related to this issue, but so far I have not found a resolution.  Following is a slight modification of the example on pages 408-409 of Brad Dayley's "Node.js. MongoDB and Angular Web Development" (the original edition, not the Second).  The set up is as follows.

Create a directory called "test" (or whatever you want) and in this directory (1) place the following file node_server.js, and (2) create a subdirectory called "static".

Here is node_serve.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/', express.static('./static')).
    use('/images', express.static( '../images')).
    use('/lib', express.static( '../lib'));
app.listen(80);
console.log("in node_server.js");
```

Next, within the "static" subdirectory (1) place the following file first.html. and (2) create a subdirectory called "js".

Here is first.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="firstApp">
  <head>
    <title>First AngularJS App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="FirstController">
      <span>Name:</span>
      <input type="text" ng-model="first">
      <input type="text" ng-model="last">
      <button ng-click='updateMessage()'>Message</button>
      <hr>
      {{heading + message}}
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/first.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Next, within the "js" subdirectory place the following file first.js:

```
var firstApp = angular.module('firstApp', []);
firstApp.controller('FirstController', function($scope) {
  $scope.first = 'Some';
  $scope.last = 'One';
  $scope.heading = 'Message: ';
  $scope.updateMessage = function() {
    $scope.message = 'Hello ' + $scope.first +' '+ $scope.last + '!';
  console.log("in first.html");
  };
});
```

Now go back to your test directory and run the node_server.js file with

node node_server.js

You will seen the message "in node_server.js" appear in the terminal immediately after this.

Now open a web browser on http://localhost/first.html .  Click on the "Message" button.  You will see "Message: Hello Some One!" appear in the browser, but nothing else appears in the terminal, i.e., the line

console.log("in first.html");

in first.js doesn't output anything.  So the queston is: Why is this?

I have tried putting "use static" as the first line of first.js, but it doesn't help.

I'm guessing that the fact that using console.log() inside the controller function has no effect is an inherent design feature of Angular, and there is nothing anyone can do to override this.  Does anyone know if this is correct?

Comment: I see no issue in your code, try doing a **Hard Reload** in your browser

Comment: Are you minifying it before publishing it. If so, console.log will not appear.

Comment: Dear Padmapriya Vishnuvardhan: Can you be more explicit?  What does "it" refer to, and what do you mean by "minifying" and "publishing"?

Comment: For anyone that may be experiencing this problem in the future, I managed to answer it myself.  It turns out that the statement "console.log("in first.html");" in first.js above does not output to the terminal, as does "console.log("in node_server.js");" in node_server.js.  Rather it outputs to the console in the web browser, e.g., if using Chrome it outputs to the console found in the Developer Tools.